# react-native run-android error: development server returned response error code: 500

Tags: react-native

I get the below error when running:
react-native run-android on ubuntu 16.04

The development server returned response error code: 500

URL:http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"from":"/home/wbar8727/Desktop/uiapp/src/MainPage.js","to":"axios","message":"Unable to resolve module 'axios

Comment: did you npm install axios? How do you import it?

Comment: I tried installing axios, but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Install axios package and then run again

```
npm install axios
```

I then go into the MainPage.js file and add:

```
import axios from 'axios'

react-native run-android
```

Comment: this didn't work, npm install axios returns an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 npm install react-timer-mixin
```

I found it here:

```
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2536#issuecomment-458082305
```